# What does "Sets are to arrays as maps are to objects" mean?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, set, maps

I'm learning about ES6 and stumbled upon this phrase in [this video](https://youtu.be/H5DJPfcN2P4?t=27) that states: 
'you could say that Sets are to Arrays as Maps are to Objects'.

What does this phrase mean ? Why is a Set more linked to arrays than maps are ? (and vice-versa for objects).

I know this is a really specific question, but my head is really turning since i've heard this phrase!

Thank you in advance, i'm new to question on SO so any comment is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Set` is a collection of values, just like an array is a collection of values (no keys involved, except `.length` / `.size`)

A `Map` is a collection of key-value pairs, just like an object is a collection of key-value pairs. (though the keys of a `Map` can be *anything*, not just strings)

Of course, there are many more differences, but the distinction between *values* and *key-value* pairs is what's most relevant for what you're asking.

`Map` and object example:

```js
const key = 'key';
const value = 'value';

const map = new Map();
const obj = {};

map.set(key, value);
obj[key] = value;
```

`Set` and array example:

```js
const value = 'value';

const set = new Set();
const arr = [];

set.add(value);
arr.push(value);
```

Comment: Oh thank you that makes so much sense now, I think the fact that i'm new to JS (came from Java) slows my 'comprehension' quite a bit. I juste played a bit in the console to get your explanation in my head, and it's much clearer now :)

Comment: I was going to add the same snippets of what i tried in the console but you've juste included them, thanks!